# Rails + Capistrano, seed production database with file uploads?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano

for a rails app, I'm using seeds.rb to populate the database with records and associated image-uploads. The seeds.rb gets all records data from a given YAML-file and grabs image-files from a folder to upload them. This works well in development-environment:

Folder Structure:

```
rails_app/
  db/seeds.rb
  ...
data/
  images1/
    image1.jpg
    image2.jpg
  images2/
    ...
  data.yml
```

data.yml:

```
item1:
  description: Some description
  filepath: images1/image1.jpg

item2:
  description: ...
```

seeds.rb:

```
items = YAML.load_file(File.join(Rails.root, '..', 'data', 'data.yml'))
items.each do |item, details|
  # create items with file-uploads, etc.
  ...
end
```

As all database-content is ready for production like this, we want to seed the production database via rake db:seed and access my local YAML-file and image-folder to create the records with their associated file-uploads.

To deploy, I'm using Capistrano and already [found a task](https://gist.github.com/stevenyap/9130882) to seed data to production...

```
# Add this in config/deploy.rb
# and run 'cap production deploy:seed' to seed your database
desc 'Runs rake db:seed'
task :seed => [:set_rails_env] do
  on primary fetch(:migration_role) do
    within release_path do
      with rails_env: fetch(:rails_env) do
        execute :rake, "db:seed"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

...Unfortunately, this task only works with the seeds.rb on the production server and thus can not find the YAML or images on my local machine.

**How can I write a task for Capistrano to access my local YAML and files and db:seed them to the database?**

(Appearantly it's not a common practice to seed the production database, but it worked well to get a YAML from the client-side with all files and already use this "proper" data for development/design)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

At a high level, you'll want to create a task that is a *prerequisite* of `deploy:seed`. That will ensure your task is run first, just before the seed script is executed.

In terms of that task you create, you want it to upload certain files to the same server and relative to the same directory as where the seed task will be run. Looking at the seed task you pasted in your post, we can see the directory is `release_path` and the server is `primary fetch(:migration_role)`.

Therefore, I suggest writing a task like this:

```
task :upload_seed_data do
  on primary fetch(:migration_role) do
    execute :mkdir, "-p", release_path.join("../data")
    upload! "../data/data.yml", release_path.join("../data/data.yml")
    # ... and so on for all files you want to upload
  end
end

# Register the prerequisite
before "deploy:seed", :upload_seed_data
```

Comment: Okay, does this mean, I'm basically uploading everything on an intermediate folder to re-upload it from there to my app? This would sound kind of long-winded to me. Are there any methods to synchronize the development with the production database? Thanks.